# error on foreign key on delete cascade creating table

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, mariadb

I am using this code to create my table and get this error: can someone tell me the problem? I have searched for syntax and nothing was different from mine

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'REFERENCES Shops(ShopID) ON DELETE CASCADE))' at line 5

```
CREATE TABLE schedules(
    shID INT,
    openTime TIME,
    closeTime TIME,
    FOREIGN KEY (shID REFERENCES Shops(ShopID) ON DELETE CASCADE)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just missed a parenthesis

```
CREATE TABLE schedules(
    shID INT,
    openTime TIME,
    closeTime TIME,
    FOREIGN KEY (shID) REFERENCES Shops (ShopID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You using same column name 2 times as **shId**

Try to use like below

```
CREATE TABLE schedules(
    shID INT,
    openTime TIME,
    closeTime TIME,
    shopID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Shops(ShopID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```